How can I hide the total count in changelist_view (Django admin)?
I want to hide the total displayed in changelist_view, as in the following image.
Django admin screen
I searched but couldn't find any way through admin customization.
I know I can modify the template, but I wouldn't like to do it.
Is this possible without changing the templates?

Why would you want to hide information on a page that only administrators can access?

Because the total text looks weird when the model name is more complex and the total is unnecessary in my application.

I couldn't find a way to hide the count text without modifying the pagination.html file.
Since there are no blocks in the code, I created the templates/admin/app-name/model-name/ folder and copied the pagination.html file there.
Then, I modified it, putting the count text line as a comment.

I used this code to hide the total count of objects in admin. (for me the reason was that when you have close to 20m rows the Django admin counting makes the page load extremely slow)
from django.contrib import admin  
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from .models TheModel

class NoCountPaginator(Paginator):
    @property
    def count(self):
        return 999999999 # change to a random number or 0

@admin.register(TheModel)
class AdminTheModel(admin.ModelAdmin):
    show_full_result_count = False
    paginator = NoCountPaginator

Note: this does not hide it, instead it just doesn't perform the count.

CYW, I've already tried this solution, but I'd really like to hide it. Thank you any way
